# How can show amount in words in crystal report in english language

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I tried to convert amout to words,i used this Function:

`ProperCase( ToWords(10000, 0) )`

The result is in french language : Dix Mille

My problem is how can i change the translation in english language and how can switch between  two languages when i need that

Thanks for helping me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

This article about changing Viewing Locale in Crystal Designer may help: https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1969993

There are similar instructions for changing Locale in applications. It's not clear what your situation is (Designer or App).

For situations where you need to switch language on the fly, the best solution is to create or get a User Function Library (UFL).